# sklearn decision tree calculating misclassified data points for each "predicted region/rectagle"

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

Firstly, credit to kamezekase for the excellent implementation for returning the x,y vertices of the decision tree rectangles for low-intensive plotting. The implementation is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import deque
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.tree import _tree as ctree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle


class AABB:
    """Axis-aligned bounding box"""
    def __init__(self, n_features):
        self.limits = np.array([[-np.inf, np.inf]] * n_features)

    def split(self, f, v):
        left = AABB(self.limits.shape[0])
        right = AABB(self.limits.shape[0])
        left.limits = self.limits.copy()
        right.limits = self.limits.copy()

        left.limits[f, 1] = v
        right.limits[f, 0] = v

        return left, right


def tree_bounds(tree, n_features=None):
    """Compute final decision rule for each node in tree"""
    if n_features is None:
        n_features = np.max(tree.feature) + 1
    aabbs = [AABB(n_features) for _ in range(tree.node_count)]
    queue = deque([0])
    while queue:
        i = queue.pop()
        l = tree.children_left[i]
        r = tree.children_right[i]
        if l != ctree.TREE_LEAF:
            aabbs[l], aabbs[r] = aabbs[i].split(tree.feature[i], tree.threshold[i])
            queue.extend([l, r])
    return aabbs


def decision_areas(tree_classifier, maxrange, x=0, y=1, n_features=None):
    """ Extract decision areas.

    tree_classifier: Instance of a sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier
    maxrange: values to insert for [left, right, top, bottom] if the interval is open (+/-inf) 
    x: index of the feature that goes on the x axis
    y: index of the feature that goes on the y axis
    n_features: override autodetection of number of features
    """
    tree = tree_classifier.tree_
    aabbs = tree_bounds(tree, n_features)

    rectangles = []
    for i in range(len(aabbs)):
        if tree.children_left[i] != ctree.TREE_LEAF:
            continue
        l = aabbs[i].limits
        r = [l[x, 0], l[x, 1], l[y, 0], l[y, 1], np.argmax(tree.value[i])]
        rectangles.append(r)
    rectangles = np.array(rectangles)
    rectangles[:, [0, 2]] = np.maximum(rectangles[:, [0, 2]], maxrange[0::2])
    rectangles[:, [1, 3]] = np.minimum(rectangles[:, [1, 3]], maxrange[1::2])
    return rectangles
```

**My Goal:**
I have the task of returning the count of misclassified data points; I need the count for each possible classification of the model. If we were to use the textbook iris data set, then 3 classes. That is to say for all rectangles we extract, I also want to include how many data points were incorrectly bounded by the respective rectangle. So for each rectangle, there should be 1 class that has data points misclassified = 0, as it was the predicted region, or `np.argmax(tree.value[i])` as seen above.

I would like to store the count as part of the `r` variable. Perhaps as follows, (using lengthy variables for clarity):

```
r = [l[x, 0], l[x, 1], l[y, 0], l[y, 1], np.argmax(tree.value[i]), class1_number_of_incorrect_in_this_rect, class2_number_of_incorrect_in_this_rect, class3_number_of_incorrect_in_this_rect]
```

Despite his code being very clean/intuitive, I can't quite find the right location to add my iterative calculation. I'm also confused about the naming conventions of the variables, here `y` is the y_axis, not the target, so it's a little murky as to what I'm going to compare `tree.predict()` with. And I'm also not sure if there is an existing reference to the total number of possible classes that the tree is handling in this implementation. I would imagine sklearn would have built-in functionality for that at least.

That's it in a nutshell; am I even on the right conceptual approach to my goal?